# Inserting the output of a query into a table created on a different server SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if someone can guide me as to how I can insert the output of a query into a table that I created on a different server from where I am running my query.

For example:

table is located on **server1** called **tbl1** in a database called **database1**.

the query that i am running is querying data located on server2.

for the insert command, would this work: **server1.database1.tbl1**

If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can reach both servers, it should be easy enough:

```
 INSERT INTO server1.database1.dbo.tbl1(list of columns)
   SELECT
      (list of columns)
   FROM
      server2.database2.dbo.tbl2
   WHERE
      (some condition here)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully qualified remote names have 4 parts: `servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename`. You can do any operation with them, including INSERT-SELECT, as long as the linked server is properly configured for updates and the MSDTC is properly configured for the two servers to engage in a distributed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert command on server2 would work but only if server1 is registered as [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in server2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) for server1, with appropriate permissions, you should be able to:

```
insert into server1.database1.dbo.tbl1
    select ...
```